# Finding no. of pairs

Tags: combinatorics

> For how many pairs of consecutive integers in $\{1000,1001,1002,\cdots ,2000\}$ is no carrying required when the two integers are added?

How to proceed?? (This is again a combinatorics question. Please post a solution even if it uses Number Theory).

Answer (score 2):

You will have to take 4 cases.

1. When the last 3 digits of the consecutive numbers are _999 and _000. Only possible case- 1999, 2000
2. When the last 2 digits of the consecutive numbers are _ _ 9 9 and _ _ 0 0.
   Possible cases- 5 (Corresponding to (0,1) (1,2) (2,3) (3,4) (4,5) in the hundredth place)
3. When the last digit of the consecutive numbers is of the form _ _ _ 9 and _ _ _ 0. Possible Cases- 5*5 = 25
4. When none is of that form. Possible cases- 5*5*5 = 125

Answer = 125+25+5+1 = 156